aspnet-codegenerator not supported for .NET 9.0
I am trying to setup .NET in my macbook using vscode and c# devkit. I installed 8.0 first but it didn't work, threw some weird error. I tried 9.0 and it worked fine.
Then I tried aspnet-codegenerator for scaffolding and it installed fine. But on using it to generate a controller I see this error.
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /Users/harshkumar/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
Architecture: arm64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '8.0.0' (arm64)
.NET location: /usr/local/share/dotnet

The following frameworks were found:
9.0.0 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?                                                           framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=8.0.0&arch=arm64&rid=osx-arm64&os=osx.14

Is this package not really supported in 9.0?
Edit: It is supported according to the official documentation and chatgpt but I'm still getting this error

What version of dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator do you have installed? Try installing the 9th one with dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 9.0.0.

Randomly installing SDKs solves nothing. There's absolutely nothing wrong with .NET 8. threw some weird error.  what error? Fix that instead. As for the current error, the error message is perfectly clear - you tried to use a .NET 8 tool without .NET 8 installed

When you install the latest generator version you'll most likely get the original error again. Whatever the original problem was it wasn't in .NET 8

and chatgpt randomly generated text is less helpful than random SDK installations. If you get an error because there's no project to scaffold, or you're running the tool in the wrong folder, reinstallation won't fix anything
